# How to pass compressed bytes through channel?

Tags: go, channel

I'm trying to compress file from buffered reader and pass compressed bytes through byte channel, but with poor results :), here's what I came up till now, obviously this don't works...

```
func Compress(r io.Reader) (<-chan byte) {
    c := make(chan byte)
    go func(){
        var wBuff bytes.Buffer
        rBuff := make([]byte, 1024)
        writer := zlib.NewWriter(*wBuff)
        for {
            n, err := r.Read(rBuff)
            if err != nil && err != io.EOF { panic(err) }
            if n == 0 { break }
            writer.Write(rBuff) // Compress and write compressed data
            // How to send written compressed bytes through channel?
            // as fas as I understand wBuff will eventually contain
            // whole compressed data?
        }
        writer.Close()
        close(c) // Indicate that no more data follows
    }()
    return c
}
```

Please bear with me, as I'm very new to Go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use `[]byte` instead of `byte`. It is more efficient. Because of concurrent memory accesses it may be necessary to send a *copy* of the buffer through the channel rather than sending the `[]byte` buffer itself.

You can define a `type ChanWriter chan []byte` and let it implement the `io.Writer` interface. Then pass the `ChanWriter` to `zlib.NewWriter`.

You can create a goroutine for doing the compression and then immediately return the `ChanWriter`'s channel from your `Compress` function. If there is no goroutine then there is no reason for the function to return a channel and the preferred return type is `io.Reader`.

The return type of the `Compress` function should be changed into something like `chan <-BytesWithError`. In this case `ChanWriter` can be defined as `type ChanWriter chan BytesWithError`.

Answer (score 2):

Sending bytes one by one down a channel is not going to be particularly efficient.  Another approach that may be more useful would be to return an object implementing the `io.Reader` interface, implementing the `Read()` method by reading a block from a original `io.Reader` and compressing its output before returning it.

Comment: Actually that is what I ended up with, but I've don't updated original code to not complicate it to much. And it would be little bit off-topic (question is about channels).

Answer (score 1):

Your `writer.Write(rBuff)` statement always writes `len(rBuff)` bytes, even when `n != len(rBuff)`.

```
writer.Write(rBuff[:n])
```

Also, your `Read` loop is

```
for {
    n, err := r.Read(rBuff)
    if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        panic(err)
    }
    if n == 0 {
        break
    }
    writer.Write(rBuff[:n])
    // ...
}
```

which is equivalent to

```
for {
    n, err := r.Read(rBuff)
    if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        panic(err)
    }
    // !(err != nil && err != io.EOF)
    // !(err != nil) || !(err != io.EOF)
    // err == nil || err == io.EOF
    if err == nil || err == io.EOF {
        if n == 0 {
            break
        }
    }
    writer.Write(rBuff[:n])
    // ...
}
```

The loop exits prematurely `if err == nil && if n == 0`.

Instead, write

```
for {
    n, err := r.Read(rBuf)
    if err != nil {
        if err != io.EOF {
            panic(err)
        }
        if n == 0 {
            break
        }
    }
    writer.Write(rBuf[:n])
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed omitting this would be nasty bug. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found working solution: (Feel free to indicate where it can be improved, or maybe I'm doing something wrong?)

```
func Compress(r io.Reader) (<-chan byte) {
    c := make(chan byte)

    go func(){
        var wBuff bytes.Buffer
        rBuff := make([]byte, 1024)
        writer := zlib.NewWriter(&wBuff)
        for {
            n, err := r.Read(rBuff)

            if err != nil {
                if err != io.EOF {
                    panic(err)
                }
                if n == 0 {
                    break
                }
            }

            writer.Write(rBuff[:n])

            for _, v := range wBuff.Bytes() {
                c <- v
            }

            wBuff.Truncate(0)
        }

        writer.Close()

        for _, v := range wBuff.Bytes() {
            c <- v
        }

        close(c) // Indicate that no more data follows
    }()

    return c
}
```